# applying formulas when writing numbers to excel

Tags: python, excel

```
import xlsxwriter
import csv

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx',
              { 'strings_to_numbers': True})
ws = wb.add_worksheet( 'output')
row = col = 2
ws.write_number(row,col,float(5.71))
ws.write_formula('D3','=C3*0.5')
wb.close()
```

Hello, I am trying to do some formulas on excel,I can't seem to implement the functions on the cells (in this case D3), However,when I change the number in excel (manually) the function is applied.

I don't have Errors when I run, but the formula aren't being Applied directly, I have to manually enter them (in excel) for the function to be applied

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you add more information to your question on what exactly the problem is? Any errors you got? What exactly do you mean "can't implement"?

Comment: @Ralf I added, I hope this helps

Comment: After running the script that generates your file, when you open the file: what is the content of cell D3? Is there a formula inside D3?

Comment: @Ralf yes, the formula is there (and it works) but the value not calculated

Comment: And if you change the value of cell C3 in Excel (without changing the formula), does it calculate the new result?

Comment: @Ralf yes the result is calculated

Comment: So to be clear: the Python script generates the correct formula in the correct cell, it just doesn't show the calculated value when you open the Excel file. But when you touch the cell C3 (the value used in the formula D3) then Excel updates the value that is shown in D3. Is my understanding correct? If that is the case then my answer should solve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199078/discussion-between-programmerwiz32-and-ralf).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a optional value to the method [`.write_formula()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_formula), so that the value is shown when opening the workbook; not every program calculates the formulas when opening the workbook, some only calculate when one of the involved cells is modified.

Citing the docs I linked above:

> If required, it is also possible to specify the calculated result of the formula using the optional value parameter. This is occasionally necessary when working with non-Excel applications that don’t calculate the result of the formula

You could try this:

```
# we need to pass a cell format to 'write_formula()' to pass a calculated value
cell_format1 = wb.add_format()

row = col = 2
v = float(5.71)
ws.write_number(row, col, v)
ws.write_formula('D3', '=C3*0.5', cell_format1, v)
```

Comment: Does this help or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a way to solve it in xlsxwriter, I suggest you try out openpyxl. It operates in a very similar way and solves your problem

```
import openpyxl

path = "\path\to\your\file.xlsx"
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
worksheet =  workbook["name of your sheet"]

cell1 = worksheet("C3")
cell1.value = 5.71

cell2 = worksheet("D3")
cell2.value = "=C3*0.5"

workbook.save(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have Errors when I run, but the formula aren't being Applied directly,

For what it is worth I don't see this issue. When I run your program I get the following output with the expected result:

[image]

There can be issues displaying formula results with non-Excel applications, which is explained in the [Working with Formulas - Formula Results](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-results) section of the XlsxWriter documentation. However, these issues shouldn't happen with Excel.